# S vs S+ STAT in processes log?

Tags: ubuntu, process

I know 's' means sleeping state in general. But what does s+ mean?

I also see the + in other states as well, such as R+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` in a process state means that the process is part of the foreground process group for the terminal it’s attached to.